Boost library in C++Builder 12.1 (Modern)
Is it, or will it be, possible to use the Boost library with the new "Modern" 64bit clang-compiler shipped with C++Builder 12.1?
I tried to use Boost 1.70, which worked with the 'old' clang compiler. But it does not work with the new one.
In the Get-It Package Manager, there is no newer Boost version provided.

If you don't mind me asking, it's the first time I'm seeing somebody use this compiler. Why not something more mainstream? (GCC, MSVC, or the unmodified Clang) What's the difference compared to Clang in the first place?

boost supports clang, since now builder C++ is just modification of clang it should work.

"But it does not work with the new one" - what is the actual problem that you are having with it? Does it fail to compile? Does it fail/crash at runtime? You need to be more specific. "it does not work" is not helpful information.

@HolyBlackCat If you have legacy C++ Builder projects it's a useful addition. The main differences compared to Clang are the visual libraries and an IDE that now has useful features... I have used nothing better for creating Windows UI apps...

@RemyLebeau Nothing fails to compile but boost is actually not available for the new C++ Builder version.

If you have access to the Embarcadero Quality Portal, you can read about the issue here:
https://embt.atlassian.net/servicedesk/customer/portal/1/RSS-554
Basically, Boost identifies the new 64-bit compiler as GCC and fails to set itself up properly for the new Embarcadero Clang-derived compiler. I suspect that the defines the compiler is creating are insufficient for Boost to identify the compiler properly, although a change to Boost's compiler identifier code may be needed. I'm waiting on Embarcadero to comment on the issue - they are working on it.
I now have a simple solution that does not involve editing the boost code at all:
In your project, go to:
Options->C++ Compiler->Directories and Conditionals
and in the 'Undefine any previous definitions' add
__GNUC__

This stops the compiler telling fibs about who it is :-)
Boost now correctly identifies the compiler and is happy or, at least, happier...
I've updated the issue on the Embarcadero quality portal
